# SQL Query to find a column name throughout the Database

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a column name that contains say MICROSOFT in my database in several tables.

I need to know the column names of all the places where MICROSOFT occurs.

is it possible?

If yes whats the query?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: is it an option to export your database to sql file and then just grep for that string?

Comment: No.I need a query which gives me all the column names in the entire database  which has a value MICROSOFT

Comment: then this might be a database specific question, because, if im not wrong, you'll need to first query a database schema to get all the table's names, then query each table's schema, to get all the column's names and then to create a specific query for such a table..

Comment: You can also take a look at this tutorial that explains how to explore your database schema: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30280/Exploring-Database-Schemas-on-SQL-Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server you can use the following query to get one `SELECT` per table with all columns that are character based

```
SELECT [Cmd]
  FROM (
    SELECT 'SELECT ''' + tbl.name + ''' FROM [' + tbl.name + '] WHERE '
         + CAST((STUFF((SELECT '] LIKE ''%Microsoft%'' OR [' + tbl.name + '].[' + col.name FROM sys.columns col WHERE tbl.object_id = col.object_id AND col.collation_name IS NOT NULL FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 24, '')) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
         + '] LIKE ''%Microsoft%'';'
      FROM sys.tables tbl
     WHERE tbl.type = N'U'
     ) [SQ]([Cmd])
 WHERE [Cmd] IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

So, if you're using SQL Server then you can run this to find all of the columns in all of the tables.

```
select
    'SELECT * FROM ' 
     + st.name + 
     ' WHERE ' + 
       sc.name + ' = ''MICROSOFT'' '
from sys.tables st join sys.columns sc on st.object_id = sc.object_id
```

By using the output of this query you create a list of all possible combinations of SELECTS for each column in every table.

This just outputs the list of all commands, now you have to execute them. In order to execute each command you have to create a cursor that will go over the entire list of results.

You're going to surround the previous `SELECT` statement with a cursor to go over each query and execute it. Thus, the code becomes something like this

```
DECLARE @myCommand VARCHAR(1000)

DECLARE c CURSOR READ_ONLY FAST_FORWARD FOR
    select
        'SELECT * FROM ' 
         + st.name + 
         ' WHERE ' + 
           sc.name + ' = ''MICROSOFT'' '
    from sys.tables st join sys.columns sc on st.object_id = sc.object_id
OPEN c

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @myCommand
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        sp_executesql @myCommand
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @myCommand
    END

CLOSE c

DEALLOCATE c
```